JSON_CONTAINS in HAVING clause adds extra closing brace to JSON_OBJECTAGG
I have a table with data we've collected from various sources.  It's got the item name, the source and the source's value.
The table looks like the following:



id
name
source
value




1
abc
web
1


2
abc
print
2


3
xyz
print
8


4
xyz
web
9



Using the JSON_OBJECTAGG() function, I can group the sources together based on the name:
SELECT name, JSON_OBJECTAGG(source, value) AS data
FROM testStuff
GROUP BY name

This correctly gives:



name
data




abc
{"web":1, "print": 2}


xyz
{"print":8, "web": 9}



Now, I want to run that query, but with a filter on the price/source, so I ran the following query:
SELECT name, JSON_OBJECTAGG(source, value) AS data
FROM testStuff
GROUP BY name
HAVING JSON_CONTAINS(data, 2, '$.print')

This seems to work, but there's a slight issue:



name
data




abc
{"web":1, "print": 2}}



Why is there suddenly an extra } at the end of the JSON data?  The HAVING clause is correctly filtering the rows, but why does it modify the result data?
Online demo: https://sqlfiddle.com/mariadb/online-compiler?id=ccf1041c-3ada-4fc9-bd77-2b0fe1428392
I'm not sure what version of MariaDB that site uses, but testing this on my local computer using MariaDB 10.11.9 gives the same results.
EDIT: It seems I can fix this by using:
SELECT name, JSON_OBJECTAGG(source, value) AS data
FROM testStuff
GROUP BY name
HAVING JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_OBJECTAGG(source, value), 2, '$.print')

I just was trying to avoid writing the JSON_OBJECTAGG() multiple times.  Also, while this fixes the issue, I still am curious as to why this was an issue in the first place.
EDIT 2: Another "fix" is to replace JSON_OBJECTAGG() with GROUP_CONCAT().
The following returns the correct data:
SELECT name,
    REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(source, value)), '},{', ',') AS data
FROM testStuff
GROUP BY name
HAVING JSON_CONTAINS(data, 2, '$.print')


This seems like a bug in MariaDB. A JSON function should never return invalid JSON. If you can, please open a bug report on the MariaDB Jira: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV

@markusjm I didn't think to check their Jira!  I looked and this bug has already been reported: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23068

Perhaps you can answer your own question since you're the one who found the answer: it's a bug in MariaDB. Including the link as the answer also makes it more visible and hopefully gets it fixed faster.

The SQL in this query is correct, the issue here is a bug in MariaDB itself.  (Link: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23068)
I didn't open this bug report, it was created July 2020!
Hopefully this bug gets addressed in a future release of MariaDB.
